# MySql: make this query faster... is there a way?

Tags: mysql, performance

There are 4 tables:

- Books   : id, name, author, ecc...
- Category : id, name
- Library  : id, name, street, city, ecc..
- bookcorr : book_id, category_id, library_id

Ids are all keys.

The query must show the categories with the numbers of books in a defined Library. for ex:

> **Library X**:
>
> Romantic (50)
>
> Yellow (40)
>
> Science (30)

This is my query:

```
SELECT category.id
     , category.name
     , count(*)      AS tot
  FROM bookcorr  
  JOIN category 
    ON category.id = bookcorr.category_id 
WHERE bookcorr.library_id = 'x' 
GROUP BY bookcorr.category_id 
ORDER BY tot DESC
```

and it's still slow, is there a way to get results faster ?

Comment: Have you tried running EXPLAIN on the statement? 

This is a good post on understanding EXPLAIN: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/07/24/extended-explain/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914145/mysql-make-this-query-faster-is-there-a-way-part-two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What indices do you have on these tables? The query suggests that `bookcorr` should have an index on `(category_id, library_id)`.

Your query doesn't make use of `Books` or `Library`...

Comment: "id" are all indexes. In bookcorr all fields are indexes.
Yes, this query dont use Books or Library but other queries yes...

Comment: @robert: Can you create a composite index that contains `category_id` *and* `library_id` on `bookcorr`?

Comment: U got it!  I create a composite index and its 10x faster :D  before: 0,4 sec now 0,04 sec 
Thanks!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914145/mysql-make-this-query-faster-is-there-a-way-part-two

Answer (score 1):

Change the query so that it would group on the leading table's column to avoid `Using temporary`:

```
SELECT  category.id, category.name, COUNT(*) AS tot
FROM    category
JOIN    bookcorr
ON      bookcorr.category_id = category.id
WHERE   bookcorr.library_id = 'x'
GROUP BY
        category.id
ORDER BY
        tot DESC
```

and make sure that you have an index on `bookcorr (library_id, category_id)`

Comment: Also this query makes the results faster!  Thanks